# how to import modules in Python / VS Code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Python and VS Code, so apologies if the question is very basic.

The code I'm trying to run uses 'yfinance', 'pandas' and 'numpy'. When I'm using the Google Colab Python environment, I can simply run

```
!pip install yfinance 
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

which works as expected.

However, I want to start using VS Code instead of Google Colab. I have Python 3.10.2 installed on my Windows machine, but I can't import the above modules into VS Code:

When I open a command shell, I can run

```
!pip install yfinance
```

successfully, but the next lines (import...) result in the following error in the Windows command prompt:

> 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

running the (import...) lines into the VS Code environment results in this error:

```
import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ import yfinance as yf
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

To summarize, the lines

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

result in an error, both when run in the Windows command prompt as well as when run in VS Code, but work as expected when run in Google Colab Python environment.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `import` lines are Python statements and won't work in Windows command prompt. You should write your Python code in a file and execute it as a Python script. I'm not familiar with VSCode, but I imagine it has a way to execute Python scripts.

Comment: Hi, when I do that, I get the error I mentioned above: "the term import is not recognized.."

Comment: IMHO this question is "how to run python code in Windows", not relative to VSCode. 2 choices: write these code as a script (`example_file_name.py`) then use command `python example_file_name.py` in `cmd`; or  execute these code in [Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html).

Comment: You are mixing two concepts here. The `import` statements are python code. You can run the python code as part of a python script (`.py`) file on in an interactive Python shell, such as an IPython shell or Jupyter notebook. The `pip install` commands are meant to be ran at the command prompt (e.g. `cmd.exe` or Powershell). In interactive python shells it is possible to also run command prompt commands like `pip` by prefixing them with `!`.